# Remove Values Which Are Nil From NSManagedObject

Tags: swift, core-data, null

I had an issue where my core data NSManagedObject always had nil values inside of it on the first run of the application. Do overcome this I thought I would attempt to check for nil values and remove them in case they are found. My attempted code is as follow:

```
do {
            let results = try managedContext.fetch(fetchRequest)
            scoreData = results as! [NSManagedObject]
            print(scoreData)
            for result in results as! [NSManagedObject] {
                
                if result.value(forKey: "name") as? String == nil || result.value(forKey: "date") as? String == nil || result.value(forKey: "score") as? String ==  nil {
                
                    managedContext.delete(result.value(forKey: "name") as! NSManagedObject)
                    managedContext.delete(result.value(forKey: "date") as! NSManagedObject)
                    managedContext.delete(result.value(forKey: "score") as! NSManagedObject)
                
                
                } else {
                
                name = result.value(forKey: "name") as! String
                date = result.value(forKey: "date") as! String
                score = result.value(forKey: "score") as! Int
                    
                }
```

The line of code 'managedContext.delete()' is giving me a hard time as it isnt properly working. Am I using a wrong method or is my code just incorrect. Any help welcome.

```
class LeaderboardTableVC: UITableViewController {

var finishedGame = 0 
var gameScore:Int! = 0
var name:String!
var date:String!
var score:Int!
var scoreData = [NSManagedObject]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    if finishedGame == 1{
        saveNew()
    }
    
    
    
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    
}

func saveNew(){
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    let managedContext = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
    let entity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "Scores", in: managedContext)
    let object = NSManagedObject(entity: entity!, insertInto: managedContext)

        let enterNameAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Please Enter Your Name", message: "This will be used to place you in the leaderboards", preferredStyle: .alert)
        
        enterNameAlert.addTextField { (textField:UITextField) -> Void in
            textField.placeholder = "Name"
            textField.autocapitalizationType = UITextAutocapitalizationType.words
            textField.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionType.no
            textField.clearsOnBeginEditing = true
            textField.clearsOnInsertion = true
            textField.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewMode.always
            textField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardType.default
            
        }
        let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil)
        
        let confirmAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Confirm", style: .default) { (action:UIAlertAction) in
            
            let currentTime = Date()
            let timeFormatter = DateFormatter()
            timeFormatter.locale = Locale.current
            timeFormatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm dd/MM/yy"
            let convertedTime = timeFormatter.string(from: currentTime)
            let enteredName = enterNameAlert.textFields?.first?.text
            
            object.setValue(convertedTime, forKey: "date")
            object.setValue(self.gameScore, forKey: "score")
            object.setValue(enteredName, forKey: "name")
            
            do {
                
                try managedContext.save()
                self.scoreData.append(object)
                self.tableView.reloadData()
                
            } catch let error as NSError  {
                print("Could not save \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
            }
            
        }
    
    enterNameAlert.addAction(cancelAction)
    enterNameAlert.addAction(confirmAction)
    self.present(enterNameAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)


    
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") as! LeaderBoardCell
    let data = scoreData[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row]
    
    if data.value(forKey: "date") as? String == nil || data.value(forKey: "score") as? Int == nil || data.value(forKey: "name") as? String == nil {
    
        print("Nil Value")
    
    } else {
    
    cell.dateLabel?.text = "Date: \((data.value(forKey: "date")) as! String)"
    cell.dateLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
    cell.scoreLabel?.text = "Score: \((data.value(forKey: "score")) as! Int)"
    cell.scoreLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
    cell.nameLabel?.text = "Name: \((data.value(forKey: "name")) as! String)"
    cell.nameLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
    
    
    }
    return cell
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

you can simply check for value if there is a value then store it to the variable as below. try the below code.

```
for result in results as! [NSManagedObject] {

    if let name = result.value(forKey: "name") {
        self.name = name as! String // if there will be a value in result for key 'name' then it will sore it. otherwise it won't let it be inside the if condition.
    }

    if let date = result.value(forKey: "date") {
        self.date = date as! String
    }

    if let score = result.value(forKey: "score") {
        self.score = score as! Int
    }
}
```

Comment: I also need to remove the value which is nil though

Comment: I cant only store the new value I must also remove the nil value

Comment: I Think the problem is after removing object from the the managedContext you are not saving the context. you should save the ManagedObjectContext after any modification. you should use managedContext.save()

Comment: Have done that already the fix proposed by @OlivierWilkinson has worked however now it doesnt fetch the data when the app is closed the leaderboard appears blank

Answer (score 0):

So your problem is that the properties of the managed object are nil, eg they don't exist. Trying to delete the values won't do anything as they already don't exist. Instead you can delete the managed object, like this:

```
do {
        let results = try managedContext.fetch(fetchRequest)
        scoreData = results as! [NSManagedObject]
        print(scoreData)
        for result in results as! [NSManagedObject] {

            if result.value(forKey: "name") as? String == nil || result.value(forKey: "date") as? String == nil || result.value(forKey: "score") as? String ==  nil {

                managedContext.delete(result)

            } else {

            name = result.value(forKey: "name") as! String
            date = result.value(forKey: "date") as! String
            score = result.value(forKey: "score") as! Int

            }
```

(Don't forget to save the managed context after)

Be careful though! If you have relationships in your model and you delete a managed object the relationship will still exist, meaning when you access the relationship objects there will be nil objects (the ones you delete here)

Edit: to ensure that your tableView is in sync with your dataSource (scoreData) add a didSet function to your variable declaration like so:

```
var scoreData = [NSManagedObject]() {
    didSet {
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

This means that every time you change scoreData the tableView is reloaded (you don't need to reload data in your saveNew function anymore with this)

Comment: will implement your solution and save context

Comment: Hi Thanks, The solution for this problem worked but for some reason if I close the app and go back on it no data is appearing as if it hasnt fetched any results

Comment: It stand to reason then that at least one of the values in your if statement is always nil. So all the managed objects were deleted. How do you set your values for the managed objects?

Comment: So basically the issue now is after I enter and input the value it does appear in the tableview however If i close the app and reopen it the previously values arent there. Furthermore when I enter a value to be entered in the core data it is being shown 2 times (duplicate) in the table view

Comment: So your input code is all good, no problems there. I think the tableView isn't loading properly, so when you input the value again and reload the tableView it then displays the coreData object that was saved before and the one you just entered.

Comment: How are you implementing the dataSource for the TableViewController?

Comment: not really sure what you mean by that. Probably means I've missed that out

Comment: Oh I mean how are you putting the scores into your tableView?

Comment: /how are you loading the coreData objects into your tableView in the first place?

Comment: oh ok Im using the tableView(cellForRow) method. Will update the post with the code

Comment: Ok cool, I'll edit my answer with a solution I think will work

Comment: Ok thanks just double checking where should I add this?

Comment: Where you declare scoreData at the top of LeaderboardTableVC